# LocalForage - push multiple items in array

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, localforage

I want to push multiple items in an array otherwise the item gets overrided.

So what I thought I could do is this:

```
   localForage.getItem("data", (err, results) => {
        console.log('results', results)
        // var dataArray = results ? results : [];
        // data.push(results);
        this.dataArray.push(results);
        localForage.setItem("data", results);
        console.log(localForage.getItem("data"));
    })
```

But this will replace the last item, how can I push multiple `localForage` items in that dataArray?

Comment: That implies that `results` is not an array.

Comment: If result is truthy but is not an array or something else with a push method this will happen. Why don't you set a breakpoint or log it so you can see what it actually is.

Comment: I tried but i dont understand why.. Here I have an codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvqjXK

Comment: Whats happened is that, at some point, you stored something that was not an array. Now that value is cached in indexedDB and you need to clear it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I tried the `.removeItem` function but it is still not working, as you see I updated my answer and managed to log it but now it get overrided every time I execute that function..

Comment: @AluanHaddad ofcourse I use f12, but I did cleared it like this:

`localforage.removeItem('data).then(function() {
    console.log('Key is cleared!');
})`

Comment: this.dataArray.concat(results);

Comment: @misha130 not working than it will log null

Comment: this.dataArray.concat(results || []); then

Comment: still not working pff

Answer (score -1):

I've just tested this with localForage and it works:

assuming var dataArray = [with some data]

1) how toreplace existing dataArray with what you have from the localForage

`localForage.getItem("data").then((results) => {
       dataArray = [].concat(results);
      });`

2) how to add to your existing dataArray the data from the localForage

`localForage.getItem("data").then((results) => {
       dataArray = dataArray.concat(results);
      });`

3) how to add to what you have in the localForage

```
localForage.getItem("data").then((result) => {
    dataArray = dataArray.concat(result);
    localForage.removeItem("data");
    localForage.setItem("data", dataArray);
  });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Gonna try it out now

Comment: And where did you set the item? Because when I log the results it returns me null

Comment: Because when I use your line of code it will still be overrided

Comment: Could you please help me out on this?

Comment: hi @Sreinieren , I have updated my answer. Maybe I didn't understand what you were trying to achieve based on the question.

Comment: If I press a button an exercise is done. So each time I press that button I want to add an item to the existing localForage item without deleting/overriding it.

Comment: @Sreinieren localForage is just a wrapper over whatever db tech your browser supports(indexeddb, local storage, etc). In the indexeddb case it's just a key value pair type of storage- which means you will override the value of the key either way with the new value - in your case existing item plus new item. But it shouldn't be an issue to override it with the new value - that's what you need => the 3) point should work for you.

Comment: @cristilaroi I tried the third one but the previous item still gets deleted/overrided.

Comment: @Sreinieren please provide a plunker where I can reproduce the issue. I have in the meantime created this plunker for you maybe it helps: https://embed.plnkr.co/vPNqpWZdwB7stBdxDaPf/

Comment: doing the following is not a good idea as each calls are asynchronous with localForage : 
localForage.removeItem("data");
localForage.setItem("data", dataArray);

You can totally get rid of the removeItem, it serves no purpose but to risk having your key deleted after it is set !
Just use : 
localForage.setItem("data", dataArray);